# How would I store file outputs as a variable under the name as myVariable in ubuntu shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

below are the outputs that I would like to store in a variable

```
./File_8.txt
./File_2.txt
./File_12.txt
./File_10.txt
./File_16.txt
./File_14.txt
./File_20.txt
./File_18.txt
./File_6.txt
./File_4.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by storing file outputs?

Comment: Is this what you want? `variable=(./File_*.txt)`

Comment: The even files that  i have posted need to be stored into a variable that i need to name myVariable, but im not sure how to store them into a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myVariable=(./File_*[02468].txt)
```

will store all the even numbered filenames in the array variable named `myVariable`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What does `ls` have to do with this?

Comment: After i typed $myVariable and it said "-bash: ./File_10.txt: Permission denied"

Comment: Use `echo "${myVariable[@]}"`

Comment: You can't see a variable's value just by typing it. That's what the `echo` command is for.